# install mysql (shell) without mysqld (server)

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, apt-get

I only need to install the `mysql` command line shell utility, and don't want to install the whole server software (mysqld). This is for space constraints, mainly, and I also don't wanto to have on my front end machine stuff that doesn't belong there.

Can anyone point me to the right package to install with apt-get, please? Or should I find the tarball and compile it myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
apt-get install mysql-client
```